# How to avoid dark colour of some programs in LXDE no matter the theme?

Tags: themes, lxde, colors, lubuntu

Changing the theme in my LXDE (that now I use although my main installation is Xubuntu 12.04) doesn't change the appearance of certain main programs - always dark. Why is that and how can I alter it? I tried changes in 'Custimize Look and Feel' and 'Openbox Configuration Manager' to no avail.

[image: dark colour of some programs in LXDE no matter the theme]

I have a lot of themes that I tested before asking the question.

[image]

and there are many others, none changing anything. Funny.

Only a limited number of programs are concerned, and I cannot tell what they have in common (java? kde?).
Beside VLC, SMPlayer and qBittorrent that are more commonly used, searching randomly, I found only a few others: Clementine, Gwenview, k3b, kdenlive.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: a lot of them one after another but they change nothing as far as these programs are concerned. in fact very little changes in LXDE through themes, as most important are the windows and icons that are set separately, while my panels are set to transparent.i will add a new image to see the list of themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a problem with your qt applications not honoring your gtk theme.

What you do is install qt4-qtconfig and set your qt applications to honor the gtk theme.

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
qt4-qtconfig
```

At least on Lubuntu 14.04.02 instead of qt4-qtconfig one should use

```
qtconfig
```

In the "Select GUI Style" box, select "GTK+"

[image: qt4 apps]

For details see [my blog](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/using-gtk-2-themes-with-qt-applications/) .

Comment: So, it's Qt, is it? (I am an unknowledgeable  under-one-year ubuntu user and tested only Xfce and now LXDE. For me all these acronyms have the halo of mystery!...) Thank you.

Comment: yea, don't worry, lots of people with more experience do not know about qt4-qtconfig