# How to install linux mint-x GTK/window theme/icon theme on Ubuntu?

Tags: themes, gtk, mint

I have just tried to install mint-x on my ubuntu 12.10 OS from different sources and unfortunately I got this:

[image]

It works perfectly, but the GTK+ theme part fails to reproduce the same theme that linux mint is using. The window and icon themes work perfectly, but the gtk+ theme doesnt. Any ideas why? I have used this source to get the latest gtk+ theme for mint-X: http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-x-theme/

SOLVED: after I ran the update manager....that triggered some changes in the gtk and now it looks just fine.

Comment: look here (http://askubuntu.com/a/162090/47206) and here (http://askubuntu.com/a/164259/47206)

Comment: Most likely than not, the theme you're using is for and older version of GTK, and your system has a newer one.

Comment: I am using the latest one.....1.0.7 of mint-X. @cipricus: I have installed that QT4 but for some reason it is not in my OS. I am using ubuntun 12.10 with Cinnamon.

Comment: I mean, the Theme is *for* and older version of GTK. Your system has a newer version of GTK. The theme looks like that because is not for the GTK version you have.

Comment: @UriHerrera What shall I do then? Or what's the solution?

Comment: Get the version of the theme that comes in the Linux Mint equivalent of the Ubuntu release.

Comment: @UriHerrera Well, I have been trying to do so...but it doesnt seem to be available anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the mint-x theme was installed, an update was necessary to trigger the changes. That's the solution...a simple update using the update manager.